# Execute ajax only after previous async call

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous, deferred

I have a function like this :

```
var a = function(){
    var that = this;
    var datas = ["data1", "data2",.., "dataN"];
    var dfd = new $.Deferred();
    $.each(datas, function(i,el){
       firstAsyncCall(el); //it does asynchrounus stuff
    });
    secondAsyncCall();
    dfd.resolve();
    return dfd.promise();
    }
```

then

```
var b = function() {
    a.done( function() { 
    //other async stuff 
    });
}
```

My problem is that the `callback` inside `.done()` is not executed after every `async call` inside `a()`.

How can I fix that? How can I execute the `callback` only after `a()` executed ?

Notice that `firstAsyncCall` `secondAsyncCall` and `callback` inside `.done()` are all `asynchronous` stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on exactly wht you are trying to achieve, but let's assume that :

- `secondAsyncCall()` is to be executed after *all* the `firstAsyncCall()` calls have successfully completed
- the "other async stuff" should happen after `secondAsyncCall()` has successfully completed.

Firstly, make sure that `firstAsyncCall()` and `secondAsyncCall()` each returns a promise.

```
var a = function() {
    var datas = ["data1", "data2",.., "dataN"];
    var firstPromises = $.map(datas, function(el, i) {
        return firstAsyncCall(el); //it does asynchrounus stuff
    });

    //At this point, firstPromises is an array of promises.

    return $.when.apply(null, firstPromises).then(secondAsyncCall);
};
```

You can now write :

```
var b = function() {
    return a().then(function() {
        //other async stuff 
    });
};
```

By returning the promise generated by `a().then(...)`, you can chain further actions with eg `b().then(...)`, `b().done(...)`, `b().fail()` or `b().always()`.

Answer (score 1):

i tried on this first time so might be wrong, or maybe not the result you want, hope it helps:

```
function firstAsyncCall(el){
    return $.get( "/echo/json/" ).done(function(){
        $("#"+el).css("background", "red");
    });
}

function secondAsyncCall(){
    return $.get( "/echo/json/" ).done(function(){
        $("div").css("border", "2px solid blue");
    });
}

var a = function(){
    var that = this;
    var ajaxReq = [];
    var datas = ["data1", "data2", "data3"];
    var dfd = new $.Deferred();

    $.each(datas, function(i,el){
       ajaxReq.push(firstAsyncCall(el));
    });
    ajaxReq.push(secondAsyncCall());
    $.when.apply($, ajaxReq).then(function(){
        dfd.resolve();
    });   
    return dfd.promise()
}

var b = function() {
    var myA = a();
    myA.done( function() { 
        $("div").css("background", "green");
    });
}
b();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Fq99A/